# foreach returns null value in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, subquery

i have a relationship object and set its resource in my controller :

```
$h_attendance=HourAttendance::with('adm','paper','faculty','program','student')
                                    ->whereRelation('adm','batch_id',$batch)
                                    ->whereMonth('date',$month)
                                    ->whereYear('date', $year)
                                    ->get();                
        
$data=HourAttendanceResource::collection($h_attendance);
```

this is my `HourAttendanceResource` file :

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        $f=$this->student->first_name ?? '';
        $m=$this->student->middle_name ?? '';
        $l=$this->student->last_name ?? '';
        return [
            'student_id'=>$this->student_id,
            'admission_number'=>$this->adm->admission_number,
            'std_name'=> $f.$m.$l,
            'roll_no'=>$this->adm->roll_no ?? $this->adm->admission_number,
            'register_number'=>$this->adm->register_number,
            'id'=>$this->id,
            'date'=>$this->date,
            'time_slot_id'=>$this->time_slot_id,
            'program_type'=>$this->program_type,
            'program_id'=>$this->program_id,
            'attendance'=>$this->attendance,
            'user_id'=>$this->user_id,
            'timestamp'=>$this->timestamp,
            'faculty_name'=>$this->faculty->faculty_name,
             'attendancev'=>$this->when($this->attendance,function()
                            {
                                switch($this->attendance){
                                    case(1): $att='P'; 
                                    break;
                                    case(2): $att='L';
                                    break;
                                    case(0): $att='A';
                                    break;
                                    default: $att='';
                                    break;
                                 }
                                 return $att; 
                            }) ?? '',
            'paper_name'=>$this->when($this->program_type != null,$this->program_type == 1 || $this->program_type == 3 ? $this->paper->paper_name ?? null : null),
            'paper_teacher'=>$this->when($this->program_id != null,$this->program_type==1 || $this->program_type==3 ? $this->faculty->faculty_name:null ?? null),
            'paper_teacher_id'=>$this->when($this->program_type != null ,$this->program_type==1 || $this->program_type==3 ? $this->paper->faculty_id ?? null: null ),
            'programe_name'=>$this->when($this->program_type != null,$this->program_type==2 ? $this->program->program_name ?? null: null) ,
            'programe_description'=>$this->when($this->program_type != null,$this->program_type==4 ? $this->program->description ?? null: null) ,
            'is_marked'=>1,
            'day_name'=>carbon::parse($this->date)->dayName,
        ];
    }
```

but when i do

```
foreach($data as $dat){
            $day[]=$dat->day_name;  
        }
return dd($day);
```

it always returns null !

but there are data in my fields , they are not null.

following is the response when i do `return $data;` :

{
"student_id": 1370,
"admission_number": "D1010",
"std_name": "Ahsana Sherin",
"roll_no": 9,
"register_number": "DM1001",
"id": 325,
"date": "2022-07-01",
"time_slot_id": 2,
"program_type": 3,
"program_id": 911,
"attendance": 1,
"user_id": 1131,
"timestamp": "2022-07-01 15:11:54",
"faculty_name": "AMAL Raj",
"attendancev": "P",
"paper_name": "New course01",
"paper_teacher": "AMAL Raj",
"paper_teacher_id": 1096,
"programe_name": null,
"programe_description": null,
"is_marked": 1,
"day_name": "Friday"
},

hope somebody can find a solution !
thanks :)

Comment: Resources are meant to be processed when sending a response to the client. If you want to transform your data in a different way than passing to as a response, you can try: `$arrayData = $data->resolve(); foreach ($arrayData ...)`

Comment: Is $data not a collection of a collection? dd($dat) and share the value, please.

Answer (score 0):

did u declare $day outside foreach loop? do u want to push all elements of foreach loop to $day or just last? because code above will overwrite $day each time with new values... guessing that u want to push all desired values in $day, maybe better structure of what you want to do is:

```
$day = [];

foreach($data as $dat)
{
    array_push($day, $dat->day_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not returning your array, but return of `dd(...)`

`dd(...)` doesn't have return value so no wonders it's `null`.

Second:

return type of a resource is an array so you should access keys like

```
$day[]=$dat['day_name'];
```

Third:

Please don't name your variables like `std_name`. You have `student_id` and `std_name` these inconsistencies will only make your code less readable.

Rule of thumb: Don't shorten names in your variables